# Add Event listener using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a clone of a div, but unfortunately i am not able to add event listener to cloned div.

I tried using `clone(true,true)` but still did not get it running.

Can some one help me out with it please

[JS fiddle for clone](http://jsfiddle.net/BpX9K/)

Clicking image next to And, adds a new div

Code i tried for adding event listener

```
$("#add").on('click',function () {
    $("#cont").clone(true, true).appendTo(".container");

});
```

Comment: Beware of duplicate IDs!

Comment: @Sandy: `live` is deprecated in newer version of jQuery

Comment: @Sandy `.live()` is deprecated

Comment: The problem that you're running into is that you're cloning and appending items that have the same id. As you know, id's must be unique in a web page or you'll get funny results. Make sure to modify the id of the appended item so that each appended item gets a unique id.

Comment: How do i change Id dynamically??? And as you can see click event is assigned to ID, now if i change id of cloned div how will click function work???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should change your `cont` `id` to a class as multiple `id`s are bad and won't work properly.

Second, use jQuery's [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method to grab the first in the returned jQuery nodelist that you get from grabbing all the `cont` classes: `$('.cont')` and then clone the node. You have to grab only the first one or you'll end up adding multiples of the div back on to the page.

```
$(".cont").first().clone(true, true).appendTo(".container");
```

Third, change the `delete` `id` to a class.

Fourth, because you're adding to the DOM you need to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) on the parent node in order to catch the events properly. Use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the nearest `cont` class and remove it.

```
$('.container').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $(this).closest('.cont').hide();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYJK8/12/)

Hope this helps.